# Delete specific row from datatable in a repeater

Tags: datatable, repeater

I have a repeater that have a button in every row, button will add some data records into datatable, so if I click that button in every row it will add more records to the datatable. I have a delete button in every row that should delete the records added from the same repeater row, so only records added from this row should be deleted. my code works fine except that it is deleting all records from the datatable. how to make delete specific records added from specific row?

my code:

```
for (int i = GRX.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    DataRow dr = GRX.Rows[i];

                    if (lbl4.Text == "2" || lbl4.Text == "4")
                    {
                        dr.Delete();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sequence number in the repeater, so I have added the sequence in every record added to the datatable and added it to the the if statement.

the altered code is:

```
for (int i = GRX.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    DataRow dr = GRX.Rows[i];


                    string seq = lbl7.Text;
                    string GRXseq = dr[5].ToString();
                    string GRXseat = dr[4].ToString();

                    if (GRXseat == "R" && lbl4.Text == "2" && GRXseq == seq || GRXseat == "R" && lbl4.Text == "4" && GRXseq == seq)
                    {
                        dr.Delete();


                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataRow dr = GRX.Rows[i];` might be selecting some values that you don't want deleted.

Try adding `(` and `)` to the condition in the `if` condition.

Also, check that the correct parameter is being passed to the SQL query that is deleting the row. You might be missing a `WHERE id = xx` clause.

Comment: Sure, but I need some more details about how you're interacting with the database.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you want, you can post your solution for further reference.